# How to map subdomain to Google Cloud App Engine Service and have main domain load static website hosted on shared hosting?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

So I currently have a static website which is being hosted via a shared hosting provider & then I have the  backend + frontend of my web app being hosted as services via Google Cloud App Engine.

What I want to do is have my main domain (www.mydomain.com) load the static site on the shared hosting & then have my subdomains (api.mydomain.com & app.mydomain.com) to be mapped/load the backend +  frontend of my web app.

I've gone ahead and added custom subdomains by going to App Engine -> Settings -> Custom domains

I updated DNS records as instructed when I added the custom subdomains.

Now both api.mydomain.com & app.mydomain.com load just fine, but now when I visit www.mydomain.com I get the following:

[image]

I can't seem to figure out why this is occurring and I am very confused. Any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you need to show us your DNS config for the domain

Comment: can you share with us more information like DNS configuration?